# How to fix the "No drivers have been configured or have been found on PATH" error?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-server

I would like to run Selenium server standalone 4 on my server. But as I try to run `java -jar selenium-server-4-beta-2.jar standalone` it throws me an error:

> **No drivers have been configured or have been found on PATH**

I don't understand what to do it. I have an actual driver file in the same directory as the jar file.

Can somebody tell me please what it means?

Comment: I think it's looking for PATH variables that tell it where your webdrivers are (chromedriver, geckodriver, etc...)  These are set in Windows settings... where Environment vars are located.

Comment: This does not look much user friendly. I cant find any documentation for it. Previous version did not require it.

Comment: https://www.browserstack.com/guide/run-selenium-tests-using-selenium-chromedriver

Comment: But as I found out Selenium server is able to detect the driver if it is in the same folder as jar file. https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/selenium-grid-4-tutorial-for-distributed-testing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you set the chrome driver path. you may want to set that

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","Your Chrome driver locaton");
WebDriver driver =new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: But this error throws me the Selenium server not selenium code. Driver is set to remote in this case.

Comment: but does your selenium code contains the path? where do you set your driver path? Like  for us, we specify driver path as a System property in command line used for execution

Comment: No the code does not. It send only browser capabilities to Selenium server.

Comment: Then you need to pass the driver path somewhere, either in command line or in code, else how would it know where is the driver

Comment: No Selenium server find it if it is in the same directory as server .jar file. The problem was that my driver was not in the same directory.

Answer (score 4):

You can also download the chromedriver directly from here:
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

and the set the "path" variable with the location of the chromedriver:

[image]

Then run the commend:

```
java -jar selenium-server-4.0.0.jar standalone
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved my time. I spent on this problem nearly 2 hours of searching all over internet.

Answer (score 0):

Try using WebDriverManager, you don't need to give a path/update the drivers ever.

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Source:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager

Answer (score 0):

I have added the driver directory to PATH, but it throws the error, too.
Finally I changed the filename of each driver, then it works OK.
For example:
change "chromedriver_79.0.3945.36.exe" to "chromedriver.exe".

Answer (score 0):

I simply moved my chromedriver file next to selenium-server-4.0.0.jar file and ran this command again and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps to sort our the problem

1. Add the Environment Variable (Environment Variable--> system variable-->
   Path-->Add the driver path)
2. Restart the machine

Answer (score 0):

Install the [Gecko driver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver)
or [Chrome driver](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/)
and then add that Path in your operating system

Answer (score 0):

Same issue for me. Setting up the driver path didn't work for me.
Quick Fix: Copy Drivers(Ex: chromedriver.exe) to the .jar file folder. Then try to run the command again. It works fine

Answer (score 0):

My issue got resolved with below mentioned steps
1 Copy driver and paste it in same folder where your jar placed
2. Add Driver location in PATH variable of environment variables